# GHC Haskell programming in Windows

Tags: windows, winghci

I have a haskell project which contains “compile.sh” file:

#/bin/sh
ghc -rtsopts -threaded -O2 -static -optl-pthread -optl-static -XStandaloneDeriving -O2 blockchain.hs simulation.hs launcher.hs

But I have a problem when I run it on GHCi Haskell  8.0.2 in Windows, I know it’s a Linux file but I have to run it on Windows,  I used Cygwin to convert it but the same error still appear which is exactly:

:11:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: complie :: b0 -> c
    • Perhaps you meant ‘compare’ (imported from Prelude)

:11:9: error: Variable not in scope: sh :: a -> b0

There is any solution to compile it on Windows with Haskell GHCi?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question lacks some essential information that would make it a [MCVE] - please add *at least* the contents of compile.sh. Also, your error message mentions `complie` instead of `compile` - make sure you copy&paste the *exact* error message you're getting.

Comment: This file contents a blockchain program, which is:
#/bin/sh
 ghc -rtsopts -threaded -O2 -static -optl-pthread -optl-static -XStandaloneDeriving -O2 blockchain.hs simulation.hs launcher.hs

And I have already copied the exact error massage. Thank you for the help

Comment: Please don't post additional info in comments - [edit] your question instead.